# How can I safely loop until there is nothing more to do without using a "placeholder" while conditon?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, while-loop, resharper, httpwebresponse

In order to call my Web API method until no more data is returned (I'm fetching it in batches, to keep each result set small, due to the 98-lb-weakling persona of the client (Windows CE handheld device)), I'm using this code:

```
while (moreRecordsExist)
{
    redemptionsList.redemptions.Clear();
    string uri = String.Format("http://platypus:28642/api/Redemptions/{0}/{1}", lastIdFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
            if (null == arr) break;

            foreach (JObject obj in arr)
            {
                id = obj.Value<int?>("Id") ?? 0;
                var _redemptionId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionItemId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionItemId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionName = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionName") ?? "";
                double _redemptionAmount = obj.Value<double?>("RedemptionAmount") ?? 0.0;
                var _redemptionDept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionDept") ?? "";
                var _redemptionSubdept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionSubDept") ?? "";

                redemptionsList.redemptions.Add(new HHSUtils.Redemption
                {
                    Id = id,
                    RedemptionId = _redemptionId,
                    RedemptionItemId = _redemptionItemId,
                    RedemptionName = _redemptionName,
                    RedemptionAmount = _redemptionAmount,
                    RedemptionDept = _redemptionDept,
                    RedemptionSubDept = _redemptionSubdept,
                });
            } // foreach
        } // if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 2))
    } // using HttpWebResponse
    int recordsAdded = LocalDBUtils.BulkInsertRedemptions(redemptionsList.redemptions);
    totalRecordsAdded += recordsAdded;
    //moreRecordsExist = (recordsToFetch > (totalRecordsAdded));
    lastIdFetched = id;
} // while
```

This works (if I check webResponse for null, it crashes with a NullReferenceException), but I don't really like my while loop, as it is never reached once moreRecordsExist is assigned false. So, I set the Resharper hounds loose on it to see if it had a better suggestion, but it just tells me, "Expression is always true" for that line, and the suggested "fix" for this is to change it to "while (true)"

I fail to see how that is much of an improvement, though.

Is there a way I can accomplish the same thing with a more sensible construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break out the loop with a `break` statement immediately after assigning `false` to `moreRecordsExist` variable, so its value will never be false in the beginning of the loop. You can make a change as ReSharper suggests and get rid of `moreRecordsExist` variable:

```
while (true)
{
    redemptionsList.redemptions.Clear();
    string uri = String.Format("http://platypus:28642/api/Redemptions/{0}/{1}", lastIdFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
            if (arr == null) break;

            foreach (JObject obj in arr)
            {
                id = obj.Value<int?>("Id") ?? 0;
                var _redemptionId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionItemId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionItemId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionName = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionName") ?? "";
                double _redemptionAmount = obj.Value<double?>("RedemptionAmount") ?? 0.0;
                var _redemptionDept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionDept") ?? "";
                var _redemptionSubdept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionSubDept") ?? "";

                redemptionsList.redemptions.Add(new HHSUtils.Redemption
                {
                    Id = id,
                    RedemptionId = _redemptionId,
                    RedemptionItemId = _redemptionItemId,
                    RedemptionName = _redemptionName,
                    RedemptionAmount = _redemptionAmount,
                    RedemptionDept = _redemptionDept,
                    RedemptionSubDept = _redemptionSubdept,
                });
            } // foreach
        } // if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 2))
    } // using HttpWebResponse
    int recordsAdded = LocalDBUtils.BulkInsertRedemptions(redemptionsList.redemptions);
    totalRecordsAdded += recordsAdded;
    //moreRecordsExist = (recordsToFetch > (totalRecordsAdded));
    lastIdFetched = id;
} // while
```

Comment: I already mentioned your first statement, and I opined that there solution was no better than my own. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @ClayShannon You are right, it isn't a huge help but at least you state that this loop can only end with a break statement. Someone reading the code won't have to chase the redundant moreRecordsExist variable. Also if you move the mapping parts to functions of their own, it should be easier to read.

Comment: I see your point; "true" probably is better than more "moreRecordsExist"; I don't know what you mean by "move the mapping parts to functions of their own," though. "While (true)" seems like a "goto" to me; that shows how bad the earlier code was, I guess...

Comment: @ClayShannon I meant the part in foreach loop. You parse some values from JObject then create Redemption instances.That functionality can be moved to a method. Also JSON serializers can directly map to custom types, you don't have parse each property.

Comment: I'm all for separating things out, but in this case I'm not sure but that would make it less grokkable for the future maintainer (even if it's me, as I have a memory like a relief pitcher); as for the JSON serializers, I'll czech that out. Do you recommend any particular one?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)

Comment: I'm already using JSON.NET / Newtonsoft; I'm using that to deserialize the object, as shown in the code above. Am I misusing or misapplying the serialization functionality?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You can use custom types instead of JArray or JObject types. Then you won't have to manually get the values.

Comment: You don't need JSON.NET or another 3rd party library to serialize. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization Oh, actually, I see JSON.NET is built in to the "official" bits.

Comment: I was able to implement your suggestion - thanks!; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508080/why-is-my-json-response-not-being-deserialized-on-my-client-into-the-same-generi/20531563#20531563

Answer (score 1):

Why not return some metadata with response, e.g. {Pages:10} ? Then you know exactly how many records you're going after.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid an additional query statement, which getting the record count to return would require.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a do..while() loop.  This gets you around the "while-loop-is-never-reached" problem... it will always run at least once, no matter what moreRecordsExist is set to.

```
do
{
    redemptionsList.redemptions.Clear();
    string uri = String.Format("http://platypus:28642/api/Redemptions/{0}/{1}",     lastIdFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
            if (arr == null) break;

            foreach (JObject obj in arr)
            {
                id = obj.Value<int?>("Id") ?? 0;
                var _redemptionId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionItemId = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionItemId") ?? "";
                var _redemptionName = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionName") ?? "";
                double _redemptionAmount = obj.Value<double?>("RedemptionAmount") ?? 0.0;    
                var _redemptionDept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionDept") ?? "";
                var _redemptionSubdept = obj.Value<string>("RedemptionSubDept") ?? "";

                redemptionsList.redemptions.Add(new HHSUtils.Redemption
                {
                    Id = id,
                    RedemptionId = _redemptionId,
                    RedemptionItemId = _redemptionItemId,
                    RedemptionName = _redemptionName,
                    RedemptionAmount = _redemptionAmount,
                    RedemptionDept = _redemptionDept,
                    RedemptionSubDept = _redemptionSubdept,
                });
            } // foreach
        } // if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 2))
    } // using HttpWebResponse
    int recordsAdded = LocalDBUtils.BulkInsertRedemptions(redemptionsList.redemptions);
    totalRecordsAdded += recordsAdded;
    moreRecordsExist = (recordsToFetch > (totalRecordsAdded));
    lastIdFetched = id;
} while (moreRecordsExist);
```

Comment: Doesn't that just reverse the funkiness? Now the while on the end will get Resharper jumping up and down, pointing and croaking, "moreRecordsExists is always true!"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does; so, I guess it's a matter of taste and style whether one thinks "do...while" is preferable to "while...do". It's been a while since I had a worthwhile do, but that, too, is a matter of opinion (the eye of the beauty beholder).