# Is returning a null generic list preferred when no data is found?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, json.net, nullreferenceexception

I have client code that is virtually identical in four different methods (the difference being the particular Web API RESTful method being called and the corresponding manipulated generic list).

In three of the four cases, I can break out of the while loop (see [How can I safely loop until there is nothing more to do without using a "placeholder" while conditon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479480/how-can-i-safely-loop-until-there-is-nothing-more-to-do-without-using-a-placeho)) like so:

```
if (arr.Count <= 0) break;
```

...but in one case, that causes an NRE once there is no more data returned from the RESTful method. In that method, I have to use:

```
if (null == arr) break;
```

I now know why, thus this:

### UPDATE

The reason for the different behavior was because the Repository code differs. Therefore, I am changing the question from "*Why would checking JArray.Count work in most instances, but cause an NRE in one specific case?*"

Here is how it's done in the three methods where checking for array count works:

```
public IEnumerable<Subdepartment> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return subdepartments.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch);
}
```

...and here's the "alternate version" contained in RedemptionRepository:

```
public IEnumerable<Redemption> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    IEnumerable<Redemption> redempts = null;
    if (redemptions.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch).Count() > 0)
    {
        redempts = redemptions.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch);
    }
    return redempts;
}
```

So, to be consistent with all four methods, I can either make all the other Repository methods like the above (returning null when no data is found), and change the test condition in the client to nullification, OR I can revert the Redemption repository code to be like it was formerly/like the others.

So the question: Which is the preferred method (no pun intended)?

Comment: Totally not related to your question but when working with Linq any time you find yourself doing `.Count() > 0` replace it with `.Any()` it tests the same thing but does not require you to enumerate the entire `IEnumerable` before it gives you a result, it only needs to check to see if the first element exists.

Comment: Thanks, Wilt; I'd say it *is* somewhat related!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely change the last method to match the previous ones:

```
public IEnumerable<Redemption> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return redemptions.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch);
}
```

And `NullReferenceException` is not the only reason. Because LINQ is lazy and execution is deferred **the other approach executes the query twice**! Once to get `Count()` and second one to get actual collection of results. If you really want to return `null` instead of empty collection use should get following:

```
public IEnumerable<Redemption> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    var redempts = redemptions.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch).ToList();
    if (redemptions.Any())
    {
        return redempts;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: BTW, I think I saw a documentary about your Park.

Answer (score 2):

You should return an empty collection.

All Linq methods (that I am aware of) that have an `IEnumerable`-based return type return empty collections rather than `null`.  Returning `null` from a method prevents you from chaining method calls since you now need to check for `null` to avoid an `NullReferenceExcpetion` (as you've discovered).